# mapper [user_agent.version] cannot be changed from type [text] to [keyword]" How to disable this mapper?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm newbie to elasticsearch. What I want to do is to gather logs with filebeat from kubernetes cluster and send them to elasticsearch. My filebeat config file looks like this:

```
filebeat.yml: |
  filebeat.inputs:
  - type: container
    paths:
      - /var/log/containers/*.log
    processors:
    - add_kubernetes_metadata:
        host: ${NODE_NAME}
        matchers:
        - logs_path:
            logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
```

I am outputting to elasticsearch,but I cant show the config. I don't have access to elasticsearch instance I only have access to kibana where I can add index pattern to match logs from elasticsearch.
I see logs from file beat where it's written that:

> "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: mapper [user_agent.version] cannot be
> changed from type [text] to
> [keyword]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper
> [user_agent.version] cannot be changed from type [text] to
> [keyword]"}}

What I found in docs is this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/user-agent-processor.html
, but I can't find how to disable this processor or even better how to omit this one field which is causing the error.

I would highly appreciate any help.